# Unable to do center edge in following design in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a design for family tree and but their edges are not in center. Has anyone worked on css for family tree.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tree {
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch-blank {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 480px;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 320px;
}

.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #888a85;
  position: absolute;
  left: -320px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #888a85;
}

.blank {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  left: -50px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  /* position: absolute; */
  min-height: 60px;
}

.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #888a85;
  position: absolute;
  left: -290px;
  color: #888a85;
}

.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #888a85;
  position: absolute;
  left: -290px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #888a85;
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
}

.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-color: #888a85;
}

.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-color: #888a85;
  /* border: 5px solid red; */
}

.entry:first-child {}

.special:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #888a85;
}

.special:before {
  /*border: none;*/
  /*content: "";*/
  height: 30%;
  border-left: 2px solid #888a85;
  top: 70%;
  /*position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  border: 2px solid orange;*/
}

.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  /* border: 5px solid red; */
}

.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #888a85;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}

.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}

.entry.sole:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 260px;
  white-space: inherit !important;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  /* padding: 5px 2px; */
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -260px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-button {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -27px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.ip:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  height: 50px;
}

.ip {
  margin-top: -110px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bottom-button {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.mp {
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
  /* line-height: 20px; */
}

.mp:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  top: -32px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  height: 30px;
}


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/


/*, .tree li a:hover+ul li a*/


/* .entry span:hover, .entry span:hover+div span, .label:hover {
 background: #c8e4f8;
 color: #000;
}
Connector styles on hover FIX THIS
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.entry span:hover+div span::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
 .entry span:hover+div span::after, .tree li a:hover+ul::before,
 .entry span:hover+div::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before
 .entry span:hover+span::before {
 border-color: #000;
} */


/*FROM BRYAN*/

.hasMore {
  border: 2px red solid !important;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#L100000,
#L200000,
#L300000 {
  top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#root {
  min-width: 130px !important;
  left: -130px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2a7ee8;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.level1 {
  max-width: 260px;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.level2 {
  max-width: 260px;
  background-color: #72abf1;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  padding-top: 3.5%;
}

.level3 {
  width: 400px;
  /* margin-top:-10%; */
  background-color: #2a7ee8;
  color: #FFF;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

.selectedDiv {
  border: 2px solid #ce5c00;
}

.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
}

.arrowDown {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  right: 9%;
  background: url('../images/arrow_down.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.arrowUp {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  right: 9%;
  background: url('../images/arrow_up.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.percentstyle {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 1%;
}

.disableTop40 {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  right: 0.5%;
  background: url('../images/disabledtop_40.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.lableText {
  float: left;
  max-width: 89%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
   <div id="wrapper">
    <span class="label toggleable" id="root" data-id="12345678">Sales
     Program</span>
    <div class="branch lv1">
     <div data-id="1465383580881" data-parent="12345678" class="entry">
      <span class="label wordwrap level1" title="asdsad">asdsad</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
       <div data-id="1465383583281" data-parent="1465383580881" class="entry">
        <span class="label wordwrap level2" title="asdas">asdas</span>
        <div class="branch lv3">
         <div data-id="1465383586673" data-parent="1465383583281" class="entry">
          <span class="label wordwrap level3" title="asdadas"><div class="lableText">asdadas</div>
           <div class="percentstyle">40%</div>
           <div class="arrowUp" onclick="changeDirection(this);"></div></span>
         </div>
         <div data-id="1465383590131" data-parent="1465383583281" class="entry">
          <span class="label wordwrap level3" title="asdas"><div class="lableText">asdas</div>
           <div class="percentstyle">40%</div>
           <div class="arrowUp" onclick="changeDirection(this);"></div></span>
         </div>
         <div data-id="1465383592673" data-parent="1465383583281" class="entry">
          <span class="label wordwrap level3" title="asdas"><div class="lableText">asdas</div>
           <div class="percentstyle">40%</div>
           <div class="arrowUp" onclick="changeDirection(this);"></div></span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div data-id="1465383619098" data-parent="1465383580881" class="entry">
        <span class="label wordwrap level2" title="ddsadasd">ddsadasd</span>
       <div class="branch lv3"><div data-id="1465387770616" data-parent="1465383619098" class="entry sole"><span class="label wordwrap level3" title="asdas"><div class="lableText">asdas</div><div class="percentstyle">40%</div><div class="arrowUp" onclick="changeDirection(this);"></div></span></div></div></div>
      <div data-id="1465387759145" data-parent="1465383580881" class="entry"><span class="label wordwrap level2" title="asdasd">asdasd</span></div></div>
     </div>
    <div data-id="1465387756240" data-parent="12345678" class="entry"><span class="label wordwrap level1" title="csadsaasdsa">csadsaasdsa</span><div class="branch lv2"><div data-id="1465387763304" data-parent="1465387756240" class="entry sole"><span class="label wordwrap level2" title="asdsadsa">asdsadsa</span></div></div></div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the *JSFiddle* link for reference:    https://jsfiddle.net/fuj5bdyh/2/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: please edit my question as per you want

Comment: You want us to help, then please, do **your** job.

Comment: actually i have created above family tree. but i m stuck in how can i center this edges of nodes

Comment: do you mean to say that you want the connectors to connect at the center of the nodes?

Comment: yes. in output you can see connectors are not in center of nodes. they are above than center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could improve but with you have already done the easier is change the `margin-top` to the half of the height in negative:

for level1 and level2 `margin-top: -25px;`

for level3 `margin-top: -15px;`

I don't use the snippet because not looks equal:  https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/fuj5bdyh/4/

Comment: one more thing that i want to ask..actually i am not designer. so here point is how can i center the text in every node. if it has more text then it should be adjusted in center only. center from top.

Comment: In the `.label` class change `display:block` for `display:flex` and add `align-items:center`. And you can remove the `padding-top`

Comment: thanks dud.. one more if i am adding more text in level3 node.. it's height will increase. so 40% text should be in center again the text. last question.. really appreciates you css skills

Comment: That's no problem, the text remain centered, but the edges are no longer in the middle if the height changes. That's more complicated to solve

Comment: edges problem is solved already. i want "<div class="percentstyle">40%</div>" should be in center. if node height will increase. this above div always in center.

Comment: I edit the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/fuj5bdyh/8/  Check the `.percentstyle` class. If you have another question open a different post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114302/discussion-between-tipu-and-blonfu).

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuj5bdyh/3/). Modified some `margin-top` options in the css.